# How to write a shell script to take the first record for a particular column?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

The following is a small file for demo. There are two columns and I'd like to write a shell script to take the first occurrence of each Name.

--- input.txt ---

```
Name,Count
Linux,2
Unix,10
Linux,10
Unix,4
Windows,6
```

--- desired output.txt ---

```
Name,Count
Linux,2
Unix,10
Windows,6
```

The real input.txt is much bigger (in GB size), so something that can scale will be great.

Also, I apologize if similar questions have been asked before (I was not able to find a solution to this  through searching).

Comment: A quick search here or on google and you would have found many example on how to solve this.

Answer (score 6):

This would do it:

```
awk -F, '!seen[$1]++' input.txt
```

`-F,` sets the input field separator to a comma. This means that the `$1` on each line is the part before the comma (Name, Linux, Unix, etc.). `seen` is an array, which keeps track of the values of `$1` that have already been seen. Every time `$1` is the same, `seen[$1]` is incremented. The line is only printed when `seen[$1]` is 0, which is only true the first time a new key is seen.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was hoping to find.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it in `awk` like this:

```
awk -F, '$1 in a{next}{a[$1]}1' input.txt > output.txt
```

Also, substituting `mawk` for other `awk` versions would definitely provide a significant speed boost for large files.

Comment: Correct way to elaborate Tom's solution would be  `awk -F, '!($1 in a){a[$1]; print}' input.txt`.

Comment: You drop `{next}` for `!(...)`, and I drop `; print` for `1` :)

Comment: I see it as `some pattern {action} all pattern {action} all pattern` vs `some pattern {action}`! `:)`